# How to Create Piecewise Constant (Bin Smooth) Model in R?

Tags: r, regression, piecewise

I've looked all over for an answer to this question.

If you have an explanatory variable x and a response y, how can you fit a piecewise constant regression model in R?

I know the `segmented` package may be used to create a piecewise non-constant model, but I cannot figure out how to constrain the slope of each line segment to be 0. I need to be able to use the model for prediction, which is why I cannot simply use the `regressogram` function.

Thanks for any help,

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in base R using `approxfun` by including the argument `method = "constant"`
Since you don't provide data,  I made an example using data built into R.

```
StepFun = approxfun(x=iris$Sepal.Length, 
    y = iris$Sepal.Width, method = "constant")
```

### Edit

I now think that the question is to break the range of x into bins and create a piecewise constant function (using the mean value of y per bin). I am giving two versions of this.  One that is easier and one that matches the OP's comments better. Both of these are done using `cut` to bin the data.

### Version 1: Specify the endpoints of the bins

This is easy if you just want to specify the bins themselves. Notice that I am plotting with a large number of intermediate points.  This avoids the appearance of any slanted regions in the plot.

```
## To specify break boundaries
BREAKS = seq(4,8,0.5)
BINS  = cut(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks=BREAKS, labels=FALSE)
MEANS = aggregate(iris$Sepal.Length, list(BINS), mean)$x

Step2 = approxfun(x=BREAKS[-1], y = MEANS, method = "constant")
curve(Step2, xlim=c(4.5,8),n=1001)
```

[image: Step 2]

### Version 2: Specify the number of points per bin

The goal of this version is not to have the bins be the same width, but instead to contain (approximately) the same number of points per bin. 
You can't actually guarantee that this can be done. If there are multiple x values that are the same in your data, it may not be possible to get exactly the same number of points per bin, but this will get you as close as possible. The idea is to use `quantiles` to tell you bin boundaries that approximate the same number of points per bin.

```
## To specify number of points per bin
PointsPerBin = 15
Q = seq(0,1, PointsPerBin/length(iris$Sepal.Length))
QBREAKS = quantile(iris$Sepal.Length, Q)
QBINS  = cut(iris$Sepal.Length, breaks=QBREAKS, labels=FALSE)
QMEANS = aggregate(iris$Sepal.Length, list(QBINS), mean)$x

Step3 = approxfun(x=QBREAKS[-1], y = QMEANS, method = "constant")
curve(Step3, xlim=c(4.5,8),n=1001)
```

Again, if you use a small number of points, it will look like there are slanted regions in the plot.

[image: Step 3]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you then use this to predict new data?

Comment: Yes.  Just use `StepFun(YourXValue)` . This will only work for x's in the range of the original x's unless you add yet other arguments to `approxfun`.  If you need that,  look at the `rule` argument to approxfun.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've just tried to implement this, and its not quite what I'm looking for. I want to be able to specify the size of the bins (i.e., how many data points to include per bin). Also, even with `method="constant"` the lines connecting the points still have slope?

Comment: There is a plotting artifact, but actually, the function is piecewise constant.   However, it does not let you specify the bins.  That comes from the data. When you say that you want to specify bins,  what answer are you looking for? Do you want the function to give the bin average?

Comment: Yes sorry I should have specified. I want the function to give the bin average.

Comment: Adding to answer.